# Siri's s speech to text not working

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition, ios10, speechkit

I am working with the siri's speech to text, But all I get is no response from audioEngine.

The audioEngine starts once and after recognizing the first text of speech, it stops, as I want to recognize the speech for certain amount of time. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
speechRecognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc]initWithLocale: locale];

audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc]init];

if (speechRecognitionTask != nil) {
    [audioEngine stop];
    [speechRecognitionTask cancel];
    speechRecognitionTask = nil;
}


AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *error = nil;

if(error == nil) {
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
    [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:true error:&error];

} else
    NSLog(@"audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.");

recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];

AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode;

if (inputNode == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AudioEngine has no input node");
    return;
}
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true;
error = nil;


speechRecognitionTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * result, NSError *  error1) {

    BOOL isFinal = false;

    if (result != nil) {
        self.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString;
        isFinal = ![result isFinal];
        [audioEngine stop];
        [inputNode removeTapOnBus: 0];

        recognitionRequest = nil;
        speechRecognitionTask = nil;

AVAudioFormat *recodringFormat = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];

[inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recodringFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
    [recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
}];

NSError *error1;
[audioEngine prepare];

[audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error1];
if (error1 != nil) {
     NSLog(@"Error discription: %@", error1.description);
}
```

Comment: Have you assign the delegate? @Vin

Comment: Yes. Authorization and assigning delegate is written in microPhone button tapped action. @KAR

Comment: @Vin, did you fix your issue? I am facing same issue with you. I would appreciate if you let me know how you solved this issue. thank you.

Comment: @gstream79 : I am not facing this issue anymore.
A little changes in the code helped me.
Please check out the changes in my own following answer.

Comment: It was the change to the statement after reading the Apple's documentation  

[audioSession setActive:true withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've solved this issue as well.

Comment: Any other way you followed to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)startRecording
{
audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc]init];

if (speechRecognitionTask != nil) {
     speechRecognitionTask = nil;
    [speechRecognitionTask cancel];
}

[self showActivityIndicator];
self.textView.text = @"Please speak the business";
 audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *error = nil;

if(error == nil) {
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
    [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:true withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];

} else{
    NSLog(@"audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.");
}
recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];

inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode;

if (inputNode == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AudioEngine has no input node");
}

if (recognitionRequest == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create and SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object");

}
recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES;
error = nil;


speechRecognitionTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable errorl) {

    BOOL isFinal;
    if (result != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Formatted String: %@ ",result.bestTranscription.formattedString);
        userFeedback.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString;


        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(endRecordingAudio) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        isFinal = [result isFinal];
        if (isFinal) {
            [audioEngine stop];
            [inputNode removeTapOnBus: 0];
            recognitionRequest = nil;
            speechRecognitionTask = nil;
        }

        [self.microphoneButton setEnabled: true];
    }

    if (errorl) {
        NSLog(@"Error Description: %@", errorl);

    }
}];


AVAudioFormat *recodringFormat = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];

[inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recodringFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
    [recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
}];

NSError *error1;

    [audioEngine prepare];

    [audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error1];

if (error1 != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error discription: %@", error1.description);
     [self hideActivityIndicator];
}
userFeedback.text = @"Say something, I am listening!";
NSLog(@"Say something, I am listening!");

}


-(void)endRecordingAudio
{  
    NSLog(@"AudioEngine stopped");
    [audioEngine stop];
    [inputNode removeTapOnBus: 0];
    recognitionRequest = nil;
    speechRecognitionTask = nil;
}
```

Comment: I added a timer to stop the audio engine instead. With this I can limit the user to speak for some minimum time duration. Otherwise you can add a button to start and stop the audio engine by user.